# Dart Encapsulation - private data

Tags: dart

I know i can create a private property by prefixing its name with an underscore (_).

but if I put the class and the main function in the same file I can **access to private properties**

```
class User {
  late String email;
  late String _password;

  User({required String email, required String password})
      : email = email,
        _password = password;
}

void main() {
  User u = User(email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: 'mypassword');
  print(u._password); // I can access to this private property
}
```

if I move the User class to a separate file everything works like expected, and **i can't access private properties**

```
import 'user.dart';
void main() {
  User u = User(email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: 'mypassword');
  print(u._password); // I can't access to this private property
}
```

I didn't understand the reason.

Answer (score 2):

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it's private to its **library**.
>
> https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts.

So basically the underscore does not make "variable private" the way we are used to (from languages like Java or C#) but it makes private to the **library** (which, roughly saying, is the same as a Java package).

That's why if you put the directive `part of 'main.dart';` in the `user.dart` and the directive `part 'user.dart';` in the `main.dart` file you will be able to access the private field, even the class being in a different file. The *part of* and *part* directives makes two files the same **library**.

---

If you are curious why Dart uses underscores instead of access modifier keywords like public or private, see SDK issue #33383 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33383.

In a nutshell, from what I have understood: since the Dart language supports dynamic member access, it's far more performant use library level visibility than class-based visibility, as @eernstg said:

> I think it's important to note that this is actually not about syntax. You could choose lots of different syntactic forms for the same thing, but it's the **underlying structure that matters**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a variable from a class, use this

```
class User {
  late String email;
  late String _password;

  User({required String email, required String password})
      : email = email,
        _password = password;

  //this is called a get function, which you can call from class instance.
  String get getUserPassword => _password;
}
```

```
import 'user.dart';
void main() {
  User u = User(email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: 'mypassword');
  print(u.getUserPassword); // changes here
}
```

Happy coding!!